# Referenciar ao "pai" da classe

Tags: c#, .net

Como faço para referenciar o "pai" dentro do método? Lembro que no Java era só usar `this`, mas e em C#?

Exemplo:

```
public class UPlayer : RocketPlayer
{

    public void SendMessage(object obj)
    {
        RocketPlayer pl = base;//não é possivel
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base` é usado para chamar um método de uma das classes derivadas, ignorando métodos da classe actual (ou seja, "non-virtual calls"). Para referenciar o próprio objecto cujo código está a ser executado, usa-se `this`, tal como em java.

```
RocketPlayer pl = this;
```

Na minha opinião, a pergunta "Como faço para referenciar o "pai" dentro do metodo?" não faz muito sentido. Não existem dois objectos neste contexto (pai e filho), existe apenas um. Esse objecto é do tipo `UPlayer`, e esse tipo deriva do tipo `RocketPlayer`.

É importante fazer a distinção entre tipos (classes, interfaces, etc) e objectos (instanciações desses tipos). Neste contexto, existem 2 tipos mas apenas 1 objecto que pode ser referenciado.